# R clusplot point shape

Tags: r, plot

I'm using kMeans and then clusplot function to plot the data, however i want to use custom point shapes or no point-shapes at all. Using pch argument in clusplot yields an errors (formal argument "pch" matched by multiple actual arguments).

Eg. in following plot change all point shapes by a custom vector:

```
library(cluster)
d <- dist(scale(mtcars), method="euclidean")
k <- kmeans(d, 2)
clusplot(d, diss=T, k$cluster, labels=2, col.txt=c("blue", "red")[k$cluster])
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example please? Yes, it is too much trouble for us to create a data set, cluster it, then plot it. We'd much rather cut and paste some code from your question.

Comment: "or no point-shapes at all"  You mean just plot the ellipses with no points?  Or do you want all points have the same shape?

Comment: All points the same shape is sufficient, but custom shapes would be better.

Comment: If you use `cex=0` you get zero-sized shapes that are invisible... Then if you can get the two components for each car then you could add points as you wish with `points`...

Comment: If you set plotchar=FALSE   it will plot all points as the same character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the locations of the points with `cmdscale`, and then either plot them first and do the cluster plot with invisible points via `cex=0` and `add=TRUE` or do the `clusplot` first and use `points` to add the dots in whatever style you want. Points first:

```
> plot(cmdscale(d),pch=19)
> clusplot(d, diss=TRUE, k$cluster, labels=2, col.txt=c("blue", "red")[k$cluster],cex=0,add=TRUE)
```

Cluster first, then points with alternating symbols just for illustration:

```
> clusplot(d, diss=TRUE, k$cluster, labels=2, col.txt=c("blue", "red")[k$cluster],cex=0)
> points(cmdscale(d),pch=1:2)
```

You might also want to use `xlim=c(-5,5)` to get the labels completely in.